# How do I put 2 different texts in one button in android?

Tags: android, xml, button, text

so this image basicly shows what I want to do:
[image: http://oi44.tinypic.com/24do2te.jpg]

I want to add static text (that orange A) on a button which already has text on it. But I don't have any idea how.

Comment: SpannableString? you need to do it at runtime

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear, can you farther explain what is it you're trying to do?

Comment: I want to have a button with two texts. One of them will be alligned left (in the beginning) and the other will be allinged center. (see the picture I posted).

I also want this two texts to be separate things because I want to give them different color and fonts.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Html.fromHTML(htmlString)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml%28java.lang.String%29). Something like:

```
myTextButton.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#FFA500'>A: </font> whatever text you need here"));
```

Answer (score 0):

With resp to @blackbelt

```
Spannable wordtoSpan = new SpannableString("A:  Text");        
wordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.ORANGE), 0, 2, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
button.setText(wordtoSpan);
```

where `button` is your `Button` object..

where

```
.setSpan(what,start,end,flag);
```

where

1. ***what*** has ForegroundColorSpan or StyleSpan or UnderlineSpan object. ForegroundColorSpan take one integer argument for color and StyleSpan also take one argument for style but UnderlineSpan don’t take any argument.
2. ***start*** has starting point of string where would you start string index for color of style.
3. ***end*** has ending point of string where would you end string index for color of style.
4. ***flag*** can have 1 or 0.

You can also change Fontsize to part of String.. [refer this link for ref](http://www.opendebug.com/article/394517)